# Automatic floating with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of elements within a `row-fluid` and `span12` that are `span4`. I want to be able to output as many of these as necessary and have them automatically line up in columns of 3. The problem im having is that this happens, but there is an offset (the uncleared float offset).

Is there a way to do this without counting each box and every 3rd one closing the previous row and starting a new one?

```
        <div id="content" class="clearfix row-fluid">

            <div id="main" class="span12 clearfix" role="main">

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4">Test</div>
                    <div class="span4">Test</div>
                    <div class="span4">Test</div>
                    <div class="span4">Test</div>
                    <div class="span4">TEst</div>
                </div>



            </div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is practically unavoidable if your boxes have varied height. You can get around this issue by using the [Masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Otherwise, you can use a fixed height for your boxes.

This happens because floated elements fall out of the normal HTML document flow and default to this behaviour when some elements are taller than their siblings.

Comment: Ok assuming I set a height for each box (which is possible for this layout).

Comment: This is an issue with Bootstrap's fluid layout. If it does not add up to 12 columns in each row, you get this offset. So ignore what I said about fixed height, that won't work in this case.